# Should homomorphisms between algebraic structures be considered functions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, group-homomorphism

Consider the map $\varphi:\{0,1,2,3\}\to\{0,1,2,3\}$ given by $\varphi(x)=x$. If $\{0,1,2,3\}$ is endowed with the structure of $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$, then $\varphi$ may be considered to be a group homomorphism between $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$.

Now consider the map $\psi:\{0,1,2,3\}\to\{0,1,2,3\}$ given by $\psi(x)=x$, and suppose $\{0,1,2,3\}$ is endowed with the structure of the Klein-four group $K_4$. Then, $\psi$ may be consider a group homomorphism between $K_4$ and $K_4$.

If we define a function as an ordered triple $(A,B,f)$ satisfying certain conditions, then $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are clearly equal. However, to me it seems natural to consider them to be *different homomorphisms*, since the groups are different – it's just that their underlying sets happen to be equal. In other words, I am inclined to formally define a group homomorphism as an ordered triple $((G,\cdot),(H,\star),f)$, where $(G,\cdot)$ and $(H,\star)$ are both groups, and $f$ is the graph of a function $\varphi:G\to H$ satisfying $\varphi(a)\star\varphi(b)=\varphi(a\cdot b)$.

Although this objection might seem unnecessarily pedantic, there seem to be genuine issues with defining homomorphisms as functions. If we consider $\varphi$ and $\psi$ to be the same homomorphism, then in the category of groups, what is the source of $\varphi$? This should be a group with the underlying set $\{0,1,2,3\}$, but it seems impossible to "know" which group it should be.

My question is: should the "correct" definition of a group homomorphism, and more generally a homomorphism between two algebraic structures, be a function satisfying certain constraints? Or is my technical objection correct, but in practice we are too lazy to care about such things?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  In this context, Groups are also Sets and a homomorphism between two groups is a function between the underlying sets.  Sure,  different group structures on the same set might create a situation where homomorphism give the same function on the underlying sets.  So what?

Comment: Phrased differently, why would you expect to be able to deduce a whole lot about the group structure from the underlying function on the underlying sets?

Comment: @lulu: "Sure, different group structures on the same set might create a situation where homomorphism give the same function on the underlying sets. So what?" In my post, I give an example of where this might be a problem. If the morphisms in the category of groups are simply functions between underlying sets subject to certain constraints, then the source and target of the morphisms appear to be ill-defined. For instance, is $\varphi$ a morphism from $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$, or is it a morphism from $K_4$ to $K_4$?

Comment: Specifying an element of  $Hom_{Grp}(G_1,G_2)$ specifies everything...or, without categorical language, just saying that $\phi$ is a homomorphism from $G_1\to G_2$ specifies everything. I don't see any ambiguity.  Sure there are relevant forgetful functors, that take Groups to Sets (or, better, to PointedSets since we  know our functions preserve the identity) but I don't see how that gives rise to ambiguity...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is one way to define a category that should resolve your concern : A category is the data of a class Ob(C) of objects and a class Mor(C) of morphisms, with two maps $s,t : Mor(C) \to Ob(C)$, namely "set and target". (There are obviously also axioms for composition of morphisms, identity, etc). Then $Hom(x,y)$ can be defined as the subset (subclass if you are picky about set-theoretic problems) of elements $f \in Mor(C)$ such that $s(f) = x$ and $t(f) = y$.

Therefore, in the category of groups, the source of $\phi$ is not only the set $G$ but the *group* $(G,\cdot)$. So concretely, $\phi$ and $\psi$ considered as group morphisms, are different maps simply because their sources are not equal. If you are concerned that $\phi$ and $\psi$, as maps (so as binary relations on $G^3$, etc) are identical, we can choose to define a group morphism as the set-theoretic data of the map *plus* the data of group law.